# Is it possible to launch Excel from a SharePoint survey question?

Tags: excel, survey

I'm about to create a new SharePoint survey and for a sub-set of input, rather than have separate questions for each data element, I'd like to launch Excel for the responder to directly input their answers as the last part of the survey or return to the SharePoint survey to finish additional questions. Is this possible?

Detail: I'm collecting information about data in databases. The first question will ask the responder for the "friendly" data element name. Then I will have 4 more pieces of input to collect about that particular data element. One way to do this is to ask separate questions in the SharePoint survey. However, I am curious if I could launch Excel from the SharePoint survey and have the responder fill out the remaining input directly in Excel. They will have to repeat these 5 questions for up to 90 other data elements, depending if it meets certain criteria. The reason for not collecting all the data in Excel is (1) because there are other overall questions to be answered (i.e. not specific to a single data element), and (2) to make the overall look and feel more appealing than adding information to a spreadsheet.